# MongoDB using async to update field in multiple collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm new to mongoDB and working with the sample_mflix database in MongoDB. I'm trying to update the email field value in the users and comments collection using the code below which is built on the starter template.js node script:
https://github.com/mongodb-developer/nodejs-quickstart/blob/master/template.js

The script works but how can I update the If condition to check if the user exists in both collections before the update.

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

async function main() {
   
    const uri = "mongodb+srv:<username>:<password>@<your-cluster-url>/sample_mflix?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

  
    const client = new MongoClient(uri);

    const userName = "Ned Stark"
    const newEmail = "nedstark@gmail.com"

    try {
        // Connect to the MongoDB cluster
        await client.connect();

        //user and comments collection
        users = client.db("sample_mflix").collection("users")
        comments = client.db("sample_mflix").collection("comments")

        //check if the user to be updated exists
        const filteredName = await users.find({name:userName})
        if ((await filteredName.count()) === 0) {
            console.log("No user found!");
          }
        
        //update email in the users collection
        userUpdate = await users.updateOne(
            { name: `${userName}`},
            { $set: { email: newEmail } },
          );
        console.log(`Updated ${userUpdate.modifiedCount} documents in users collections`);
        
        //update email in the comments collection
        commentUpdate = await comments.updateMany(
            { name: `${userName}`},
            { $set: { email: newEmail } },
        );

        console.log(`Updated ${commentUpdate.modifiedCount} documents in comments collections`);


        } catch (err) {
          console.error(`Something went wrong: ${err}`);
        }
        finally {
        await client.close();
        }
    }

main().catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0):

use Promise.all like this

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

async function main() {
   
    const uri = "mongodb+srv:<username>:<password>@<your-cluster-url>/sample_mflix?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

  
    const client = new MongoClient(uri);

    const userName = "Ned Stark"
    const newEmail = "nedstark@gmail.com"

    try {
        // Connect to the MongoDB cluster
        await client.connect();

        //user and comments collection
        users = client.db("sample_mflix").collection("users")
        comments = client.db("sample_mflix").collection("comments")

        //check if the user to be updated exists
        
        Promise.all([
          users.find({name:userName}).toArray(),
          comments.find({name:userName}).toArray()
        ])
    .then(result=>{
          if (result[1].length && result[0].length>0)
      {
 //update email in the users collection
        userUpdate = await users.updateOne(
            { name: `${userName}`},
            { $set: { email: newEmail } },
          );
        console.log(`Updated ${userUpdate.modifiedCount} documents in users collections`);
        
        //update email in the comments collection
        commentUpdate = await comments.updateMany(
            { name: `${userName}`},
            { $set: { email: newEmail } },
        );

        console.log(`Updated ${commentUpdate.modifiedCount} documents in comments collections`);

      }
       })
    
       

        } catch (err) {
          console.error(`Something went wrong: ${err}`);
        }
        finally {
        await client.close();
        }
    }

main().catch(console.error);
```